# Getting Error io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl cannot be cast to io.restassured.response.Response

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I am getting the following error upon running the test. I am trying to print the API response to a file, however the test is failing and throwing the error. The response of the call is in JSON and is in GZIP. 
Any thoughts and ideas are greatly appreciated.

Error : 
    io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl cannot be cast to io.restassured.response.Response

Here is my code :

```
package TestPackage;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import io.restassured.response.Response;


public class ApiServerTest {

    String baseQAURL = "http://some:8282/getworkitemwithtime";


    @Test
    public void apiServerTest() throws FileNotFoundException{

        Response srvrResponse = (Response) given().
                                param("starttime", "2017-08-10T11:17:00").
                                param("endtime", "2017-08-10T11:17:01").
                                when().
                                get(baseQAURL).
                                then().
                                log().
                                all();

            System.out.println(srvrResponse.getStatusCode());
            Assert.assertEquals(srvrResponse.getStatusCode(), 200);

            srvrResponse.asString();
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Test\\output.txt"));
            System.setOut(out);


    }

}
```

Comment: What you get after `get(baseQUARL).then()...` is a `ValidatableResponse`, you can try and use `get(baseQAURL).then().extract().response()` to get a `Response` object back.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew. get(baseQAURL).then().extract().response() worked like a charm. I got the response - I think using extract() made all the difference. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Comments are right - you need to extract your response to be used out of request context.

Actually you may optimize your code:

```
import io.restassured.config.LogConfig;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.config;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

public class TestLogging {

    String baseQAURL = "https://httpbin.org/get";

    @Test
    public void apiServerTest() throws FileNotFoundException {
        config = config().logConfig(new LogConfig().defaultStream(new PrintStream(new File("C:\\Test\\output.txt"))));

        given().
                param("starttime", "2017-08-10T11:17:00").
                param("endtime", "2017-08-10T11:17:01").
                when().
                get(baseQAURL).
                then().
                log().
                all()
                .assertThat().statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this solution too and worked perfectly. I actually got two implementations for two cases - Thank you for the suggestions. good learning and its very encouraging to try something new.